# How to match words and ignore multiple spaces?

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed, grep

The following syntax should match the "Ambari Server running", but how to match in case there are multiple spaces between words? How to ignore spaces between words?

```
echo "Ambari Server      running"  | grep -i "Ambari Server running"
echo "Ambari     Server running"   | grep -i "Ambari Server running"
echo "     Ambari Server running"  | grep -i "Ambari Server running"
```

The expected results should be:

```
Ambari Server running
Ambari Server running
Ambari Server running
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `tr` with its `-s` option to compress consecutive spaces into single spaces and then `grep` the result of that:

```
$ echo 'Some   spacious  string' | tr -s ' ' | grep 'Some spacious string'
Some spacious string
```

This would however not remove flanking spaces completely, only compress them into a single space at either end.

Using `sed` to remove the flanking blanks as well as compressing the internal blanks to single spaces:

```
echo ' Some   spacious  string' |
sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//; s/[[:blank:]]*$//; s/[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/ /g'
```

This could then be passed through to `grep`.

Answer (score 7):

Use Regex operator `+` to indicate one or more of the preceding token, space in this case. So the pattern would be `\+`:

```
echo "Ambari Server      running"  | grep -i "Ambari \+Server \+running"
```

I would suggest to use character class `[:blank:]` to match any horizontal whitespace, not just plain space, if you are unsure:

```
echo "Ambari Server      running"  | grep -i "Ambari[[:blank:]]\+Server[[:blank:]]\+running"
```

---

On the other hand, if you want to keep just one space between words, use `awk`:

```
echo "Ambari Server      running"  | \
    awk '$1=="Ambari" && $2=="Server" && $3=="running" {$1=$1; print}'
```

- `$1=="Ambari" && $2=="Server" && $3=="running"` matches the desired three fields
- `{$1=$1}` rebuilds the record with space as the new separator
- `{print}` prints the record

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to ignore all the space in between you can use `echo your  text  |tr -d [[:space:]]| grep "yourtext"` but the output will not have any space.
Example:

```
echo "Hi This   Is Test" |tr -d [[:space:]] |grep HiThisIsTest
```

Output:

```
HiThisIsTest
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the main question of `How to match words and ignore multiple spaces?` Something like the following will help you get what you need:

```
echo "Ambari Server      running"  | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | grep -E '\s*ambari\s+server\s+running\s*'
```

It takes the input and makes it lower case then searches for matches that are lower case. We use `\s*` for 0 or more whitespace (so will include tabs etc.) and `\s+` for 1 or more whitespace.

If your input was in a file like `foo2.txt` below:

```
Ambari Server      running 
Ambari     Server running
     Ambari Server running
```

Then you could do something like:

```
cat foo2.txt | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | grep -E '\s*ambari\s+server\s+running\s*'
ambari server      running
ambari     server running
     ambari server running
```

If you are just interested in the count, you can modify it a little to be like:

```
cat foo2.txt | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | grep -E '\s*ambari\s+server\s+running\s*' | wc -l
```